# Split string by full stop in php exclude "a.m."

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I am using the `preg_split` function in PHP to split a paragraph to be several sentences.

In my case:

```
$str = 'Applicants can check the final result of Admissions through the online enquiry system. The online enquiry system will be available from 10:00 a.m. on November 16 (Wednesday).';

$arr = preg_split('/\./', $str);
```

How can I exclude the case when there is an `a.m.` or `p.m.`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` to block the `am/pm` matches. You can read more about the approach here, http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html.

```
[ap]\.m\.(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\.
```

Regex Demo: https://regex101.com/r/uD9xD7/1

Demo: https://eval.in/548705

PHP Usage:

```
$str = 'Applicants can check the final result of Admissions through the online enquiry system. The online enquiry system will be available from 10:00 a.m. on November 16 (Wednesday).';

$arr = preg_split('/[ap]\.m\.(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\./', $str);

print_r($arr);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Applicants can check the final result of Admissions through the online enquiry system
    [1] =>  The online enquiry system will be available from 10:00 a.m. on November 16 (Wednesday)
    [2] => 
)
```

If `A.M.` should also be allowed use the `i` [modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

Comment: It works. Thank you very much. This case is quite difficult for a Regex beginner.